# Adding 1 on 1 video calling to application

Tags: azure, video

Where do i find the id for remote viewing? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/azure-samples/communication-services-javascript-quickstarts/add-1-on-1-video-calling-to-your-application/

Answer (score 0):

Have you follow the official links in the top of the page you've shared?

Get the connection string

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/communication-services/quickstarts/create-communication-resource?tabs=windows&pivots=platform-azp#access-your-connection-strings-and-service-endpoints

then

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/communication-services/quickstarts/access-tokens?pivots=programming-language-javascript#authenticate-the-client

Comment: i followed instructions on getting access tokens & user id. Each time i use a script it returns id and token, but not applicable for starting a call.

Answer (score 0):

```
let identityResponse = await identityClient.createUser();
console.log(`\nCreated an identity with ID: ${identityResponse.communicationUserId}`);

let identityResponse2 = await identityClient.createUser();
console.log(`\nCreated an identity with ID: ${identityResponse2.communicationUserId}`);



let tokenResponse = await identityClient.getToken(identityResponse,["voip"]);
const { token, expiresOn } = tokenResponse;
console.log(`\nIssued an access token with 'voip' scope that expires at 
${expiresOn}:`);
console.log(token);

let tokenResponse2 = await identityClient.getToken(identityResponse2,["voip"]);
const { token2, expiresOn2 } = tokenResponse2;
console.log(`\nIssued an access token with 'voip' scope that expires at 
${expiresOn2}:`);
console.log(token2);
```

Also i can only get just 1 access-token

```
Issued an access token with 'voip' scope that expires at undefined:
undefined
```